Is it really difficult to test these “Service” methods in this Rust Clean Architecture proposal? Is there some other catch I'm not considering?
I reproduced a small example of kerkour's Rust Clean Architecture on the Rust Playground.
The code is just an example and the methods code makes no sense at all.
This architecture leaks DB information to the service layer (for example methods like: find_namespace_and_membership have db: &DB argument with pub type DB = sqlx::PgPool).
This is because, quoting the author:

You may ask: Why put the db in the Service and not in the repository if it's the repository that interacts with the database?


Because we will sometimes need to call the repository's methods within transactions. So we need the repository's methods to be generics over 'normal' database operations and transactions.

I just one one question for you: Is it really difficult to test Service methods like find_namespace_and_membership without using a real DB and mocking it?
I don't know where to start, but if this is feasible I can use this architecture instead of other ones because it is much, much more practical and RAD.
I examined other architectures today (this one for example) and this is the most RAD one!
There are actually two questions, excuse me: is there something untestable / unscalable that I'm missing in this architecture right now?
I'm posting the code here too:
/*
[dependencies]
async-trait = { version = "0.1.81", default-features = false }
sqlx = { version = "0.7.4", default-features = false, features = [
    "macros",
    "postgres",
    "runtime-tokio",
] }
tokio = { version = "1.38.0", default-features = false, features = [
    "signal",
    "macros",
    "process",
    "rt-multi-thread",
] }
*/

use sqlx::{self, PgConnection, PgExecutor, PgPool};
use std::sync::Arc;

pub type DB = PgPool;
pub trait Queryer<'c>: PgExecutor<'c> {}

impl<'c> Queryer<'c> for &PgPool {}
impl<'c> Queryer<'c> for &'c mut PgConnection {}

pub struct Repository {}

impl Repository {
    pub fn new() -> Repository {
        Repository {}
    }
}

pub mod kernel {
    use crate::{Queryer, DB};

    pub struct Repository {}

    impl Repository {
        pub fn new() -> Repository {
            Repository {}
        }
    }

    pub struct Service {
        repo: Repository,
        // db: DB,
        // config: Arc<Config>,
        // queue: Arc<dyn drivers::Queue>,
        // mailer: Arc<dyn drivers::Mailer>,
        // storage: Arc<dyn drivers::Storage>,
        // and so on...
    }

    #[derive(sqlx::FromRow, Debug, Clone)]
    pub struct Namespace {
        pub id: String,
        pub membership: String,
    }

    impl Repository {
        pub async fn find_namespace_by_id<'c, C: Queryer<'c>>(
            &self,
            db: C,
            namespace_id: &str,
        ) -> Result<Namespace, String> {
            const QUERY: &str = "SELECT * FROM kernel_namespaces WHERE id = $1";

            match sqlx::query_as::<_, Namespace>(QUERY)
                .bind(namespace_id)
                .fetch_optional(db)
                .await
            {
                Err(err) => Err(err.to_string()),
                Ok(None) => Err("Error::NamespaceNotFound".to_string()),
                Ok(Some(res)) => Ok(res),
            }
        }
    }

    impl Service {
        pub async fn find_namespace_and_membership(
            &self,
            db: &DB,
            namespace_id: &str,
        ) -> Result<String, String> {
            let namespace = self.repo.find_namespace_by_id(db, namespace_id).await?;

            // do something else here

            Ok(namespace.membership)
        }
    }
}

pub struct Service {
    repo: Repository,
    db: DB,
    kernel_service: Arc<kernel::Service>,
    // and others too...
}

pub struct EmptyTrashInput {
    pub namespace_id: String,
}

impl Repository {
    pub async fn detach_all_trashed_files_from_namespace<'c, C: Queryer<'c>>(
        &self,
        db: C,
        namespace_id: &str,
    ) -> Result<(), String> {
        const QUERY: &str = "UPDATE files SET updated_at = $1, parent_id = NULL, namespace_id = NULL WHERE namespace_id = $2 AND trashed_at IS NOT NULL";

        match sqlx::query(QUERY)
            .bind("now()")
            .bind(namespace_id)
            .execute(db)
            .await
        {
            Err(err) => Err(err.to_string()),
            Ok(_) => Ok(()),
        }
    }
}

mod empty_trash {
    use super::Service;

    impl Service {
        pub async fn empty_trash(&self, namespace_id: &str) -> Result<(), String> {
            let namespace = self
                .kernel_service
                .find_namespace_and_membership(&self.db, namespace_id)
                .await?;

            // let trashed_files = self.repo.find_all_trashed_files(&self.db, namespace.id).await?;

            // for file in trashed_files {
            //     namespace.used_storage -= file.size;
            // }

            let mut tx = self.db.begin().await.unwrap();

            self.repo
                .detach_all_trashed_files_from_namespace(&mut *tx, &namespace)
                .await?;

            // self.kernel_service.update_namespace(&mut tx, &namespace).await?;

            tx.commit().await.unwrap();

            Ok(())
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}


Yeah, DB shouldn't be a type alias, but rather a struct that wraps sqls::PgPool as private field. That's a minor mistake. More important is your question about tests. In order to replace database with something else you need some kind of polymorphism. So DB now becomes a trait. You can then provide different implementations. However to avoid leakage the only way I see is to pass DB as dyn reference. Which has runtime overhead. Otherwise either you deal with very unsafe code, or some kind of leakage occures.

@freakish how much overhead?

Not much. If i/o is involved (which seems to be the case) then it won't be noticable at all.
